# I want to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
RIGHT JOIN files ON posts.id = files.fileable_id 
GROUP BY posts.id 
HAVING posts.user_id = 3125
```

It works, but I need to convert it to Laravel eloquent I tried this code

```
 $postsHaveFileCount = DB::table('posts')
                     ->rightJoin('files', 'posts.id', '=', 'files.fileable_id')
                     ->groupBy('posts.id')
                     ->having('posts.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                     ->get()->count();
  echo $postsHaveFileCount;
```

But i have this error

> (2/2) QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1055 Expression #17 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'staff.files.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from
>   `posts` right join `files` on `posts`.`id` = `files`.`fileable_id`
>   group by `posts`.`id` having `posts`.`user_id` = 3125)

I will be thanks for all to help me to solve the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the version of MySQL that you are using when you decided to convert this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using group by, you have to set ONLY the columns which are used in the group by statement in the 'select' section. If you are not using any values at 'select', Laravel will automatically pick all the columns which gives the above error. Check the modified code below

```
    $postsHaveFileCount = DB::table('posts')
                    ->select('posts.id')
                    ->rightJoin('files', 'posts.id', '=', 'files.fileable_id')
                    ->groupBy('posts.id', 'posts.user_id')
                    ->having('posts.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->get()->count();
    echo $postsHaveFileCount;
```

Comment: Thanks it works will but what about if i want edit eloquent to apply rightjoin and as in the following sql query 
SELECT * FROM posts 
    RIGHT JOIN files 
    ON posts.id = files.fileable_id 
    AND files.fileable_type = 'App\\Post'
    GROUP BY posts.id 
    HAVING posts.user_id = 3125

I tried this code but it is not work

Comment: You cannot use AND condition on Join statement. Use Where clause instead

Comment: thanks a alot where works fin thanks for your help my friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Copy and paste following statement in your code and run it.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Run the

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

change the SQL Mode for Your MySQL Server Instance

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

another way would be using the mysql configs
*go to /etc/mysql/my.cnf*

```
**add a section for [mysqld] and right below it add the statement sql_mode = ""
restart the mysql service $ sudo systemctl restart mysql**
```